# Languages and Frameworks for creating High Load Web Service?

Tags: java, .net, c++, web-services, grails

Maybe, i'm duplicating some existing theme (close this one if it's true) but i'm planning to work with high load web services and curios about best practices.

I have projects on Java and Grails. I'm doubt if Grails is right solution for high load service but Java (without any Hibernate or similar tools) can be used very well.

Anyway, what about best practices ? Does Java is good one or high load world is only for C++ and .NET technologies ?

Comment: It's not about the platform or the language or the framework. It's about how *you* use them.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer, let's imagine that we have to create RESTful Web Service. Server has access to some DB and performs computations(or data manipulation - it could be even some billing system or high popular news site). Client has Web Interface. Also, there are exists some "fat" clients which performs content management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java *can* handle heavy loads.  See http://www.jboss.org/netty/performance/20090607-asalihefendic.html which discuss how to have hundred thousand simultaneous comet connections open to a single server.  Not bad.

Note, that this kind of scalability does not come out of nowhere.  Your application must be well written in the first place and carefully integrated with the web container.  You should therefore set up a testing scenario which can put high load on your web application to see how it behaves.  JMeter can help doing that.